# SQL query between issue

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to create filtered search with opportunity to select prices `from` `to`

HTML:

```html
<select id="selectbox2" name="from">
        <option value="x">Choose</option>
        <option value="500">500</option>
        <option value="1000">1000</option>
        <option value="1500">1500</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
        <option value="2500">2500</option>
        <option value="3000">3000</option>
        <option value="4000">4000</option>
</select>
<select id="selectbox2" name="to">
        <option value="x">Choose</option>
        <option value="500">500</option>
        <option value="1000">1000</option>
        <option value="1500">1500</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
        <option value="2500">2500</option>
        <option value="3000">3000</option>
        <option value="4000">4000</option>
</select>
```

PHP:

```php
if ((isset($_GET['features'])) && ($to!='x') && ($from!='x') ){    
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM baldas WHERE kategorija = '$id2' 
        AND $features = 1  AND kaina BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' 
        ORDER BY pavadinimas_lt  LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage") or die(mysql_error());
}
elseif ((isset($_GET['features'])) && ($to!='x') && ($from=='x') ){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM baldas WHERE kategorija = '$id2'
        AND $features = 1 AND kaina BETWEEN '$from' AND 500000 
        ORDER BY pavadinimas_lt  LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage") or die(mysql_error());
}
elseif ((isset($_GET['features'])) && ($to=='x') && ($from!='x') ){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM baldas WHERE kategorija = '$id2' 
        AND $features = 1 AND kaina BETWEEN 0 AND '$to' 
        ORDER BY pavadinimas_lt  LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

The part  `if ((isset($_GET['features'])) && ($to!='x') && ($from!='x') )` is working fine, but when `to` or `from` is equal `x` is giving no results. Where is the problem?

Comment: your code is extremely ugly and unreadable. Can you lease learn some basics of code indention and format your snippet to make it readable for anyone? thanks.

Comment: Using prepared statements would make a lot of sense here, since the only thing that's different between the queries is the range.

Comment: @flesk nope, it would not. as the only one query being run actually

Comment: @Col: That is obvious, but it would make the code much more readable.

Comment: $flesk Nope, it wouldnt. There is not much difference between `$offset` and `:offset` to make it that different. Not to mention that anonymous `?`s would make it actually LESS readable.

Comment: @Col: What I mean is preparing the statement once before the if block, then bind parameters and execute depending on the conditions. If you don't think that's more readable I guess it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @flesk you can do exactly the same without prepared statements - have one query and only fill different variables. It is matter of programmer's experience, not some tool to use. prepared statements won't make this code more concise per se.

Comment: @flesk thanks for the pointing that out though. I thought at first it was a regular conditional conditions query.

Comment: @Col: Yeah, that's true. Setting some `$lowerLimit` and `$upperLimit` within the block and then running the query if they're defined with the original query would be more concise than prepared statements. That would also eliminate the need for three almost identical queries, which was what I thought looked messy in the posted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
elseif ((isset($_GET['features'])) && ($to=='x') && ($from!='x') ){
```

is wrong, because there you check BETWEEN 0 AND '$to'. And you check $to for 'x' so that turns out wrong ( BETWEEN 0 AND 'X'). I'd recommend echo'ing the SQL Queries. You can easily fix this by changing the conditional parameters.

Comment: A similar mistake is made in the `$to != 'x'` branch.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic can be simplified. Instead of three separate selects, try building your query in parts:

```
if (isset($_GET['features'])) {    

    $query = "SELECT * FROM baldas WHERE kategorija = '$id2' AND $features = 1 ";

    if ($from != 'x')
    {
        $query .= "AND kaina > $from ";
    }

    if ($to != 'x')
    {
        $query .= "AND kaina < $to ";
    }

    $query .= "ORDER BY pavadinimas_lt LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve most of your issues and greatly simplify the code by losing the 'x' literal and placing real values as the defaults:

```
<select id="selectbox2" name="from">
    <option value="0">Choose</option>

<select id="selectbox2" name="to">
        <option value="5000">Choose</option>
```

You would then only need a single SQL statement with `BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'`

Among the many other potential problems is the data type of kiana. Is it really a string in which case `'500' > '1000'`  evaluates to "true" which is probably not what you want. If kiana is indeed defined as a numeric type the the condition in the SQL should read  `BETWEEN $from AND $to`

Answer (score 0):

You have no else if for if both are equal to x

```
 else {
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM baldas WHERE kategorija = '$id2' 
 AND $features = 1 AND kaina
 ORDER BY pavadinimas_lt  LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage") or die(mysql_error());}
```

--- OR ---

```
 elseif ((isset($_GET['features'])) && ($to=='x') && ($from=='x') ){
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM baldas WHERE kategorija = '$id2' 
 AND $features = 1 AND kaina
 ORDER BY pavadinimas_lt  LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage") or die(mysql_error());}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
if ((isset($_GET['features'])) && ($to<='x') && ($from>='x') )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the case where both are 'X'

```
elseif ((isset($_GET['features'])) && ($to!='x') && ($from=='x') ){
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM baldas WHERE kategorija = '$id2'
 AND $features = 1 AND kaina BETWEEN 0 AND 500000 
 ORDER BY pavadinimas_lt  LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage") or die(mysql_error());}
```

On another note, you should remove the '' around the numeric values. They will force your database to do a conversion between varchar and int and that will just slow things down. Possibly also inhibit the indexes to work.

Answer (score 0):

As `@flesk` pointed out in the comments, this code being extremely redundant.
And have to be shortened to just

```
if ((isset($_GET['features'])) {    
  if ($from == 'x') {
    $from   = 0;
  } 
  if ($to == 'x') {
    $to   = 500000;
  } 
  $query = "SELECT * FROM baldas WHERE kategorija = '$id2' 
              AND $features = 1 AND kaina BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' 
              ORDER BY pavadinimas_lt  LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage"
}
```